# PS Getting file attribute - special characters in the path

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to eventually read a list of filenames from a CSV and get the bitrate (among other things). My issue in testing is that special characters cause it to blow up.  I tried using -Literalpath and @ but it doesn't seem to work when using the shell.

```
$file='c:\music\track 1 (3 CD) [2013]\01. Dj Fresh (Ft. Sian Evans) - Louder.mp3'

$Namespace = Split-Path  $file
$Leaf = Split-Path $file -Leaf

$shell = new-object -com shell.application
$folder = $shell.namespace($Namespace)
$item = $folder.Items().Item($Leaf)
write-output $item.ExtendedProperty('System.Audio.EncodingBitrate')
```

Comment: *"special characters cause it to blow up"* - what error message is there, and on which line does it occur?

Comment: That being said, your sample works fine in my tests, no matter whether there are brackets, parentheses, German umlauts, or Chinese characters anywhere in the path. I suspect your problem is that you are already reading that CSV file without specifying an encoding (or without specifying the correct encoding).

Comment: I think I figured it out.  It was because I was using a mapped network drive.  When I used a UNC path it works.

Comment: To help others who might run into the same problem, please add the error message you got, and write a quick answer that shows what the issue was.

Comment: I haven't figured it out actually. It works on my c drive fine but when a file is on a network share (NAS) it fails on the $items line. $folders is null.  I created the same exact path on my c drive and it works.  Using the drive letter or UNC doesn't seem to matter.  The special characters were a red herring.

Comment: Ah. I suspect that a folder situated on the NAS is not part of the Windows namespace and therefore the `$shell.namespace()` call fails (=returns null).